# Magento as a product information management (PIM) tool for multiple marketplaces (ebay, amazon, Rakuten, etc)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attribute-set, category-attribute

We are selling products on over 10 different platforms, each of which has different category sets. Also, we are selling internationally and a product can belong to different categories on different country shops of the same platform. For example, category A on eBay UK and category B on eBay FR. So the case is, considering the country shops we have, at most a product can belong to 36 different categories in the PIM system that we wish to develop a Magento CE into.

A category is corresponding to an attribute set. I think it is possible that we import all attribute sets from those platforms to PIM. However, a product in Magento can only be assgined to one attribute set, which means I need to first combine over 10 attribute sets into one and then assign it to the product. That is too much of work and might overwhelm the system.

Is there a solution to what we want to do with the system? Is it possible to have multiple attribute sets for a single product without actually creating a new big combined attribute set? Or, can we create multiple products in the system for the identical product, each for a store view? (website=platform, store=store view=country shop) so that I can assign each of them a smaller attribute set on platform level. I know Magento was not designed this way, but is it worth trying?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome 李程腾 to MageOverflow!

Why do you want to misuse an ecommerce system like magento as a PIM? What about using something like:

- http://www.akeneo.com/
- https://www.pimcore.org

> Is there a solution to what we want to do with the system?

You can do *ANYTHING* with magento - How big is your budget? I think you know what I mean.

> Is it possible to have multiple attribute sets for a single product without actually creating a new big combined attribute set?

No, I don't see any way to do this. Magento is not designed to use multiple attribute sets, therefore you have to rewrite the whole system - bad idea.

> Or, can we create multiple products in the system for the identical product, each for a store view? (website=platform, store=store view=country shop) so that I can assign each of them a smaller attribute set on platform level.

If the products have different SKUs you can try this. But having multiple magento products for the same product is absurd. If you do this, after finishing the project, you need a PIM :-p

> I know Magento was not designed this way, but is it worth trying?

No.

Comment: add answers for the questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think to implement just Magento, it is not enough if you want to manage product information for different marketplaces simultaneously. It is more suitable to use PIM systems such as Akeneo or TreoPIM. 
If we to talk about TreoPIM there are connectors for [Magento 1](https://treopim.com/store/magento1-connector)  and [Magento 2](https://treopim.com/store/magento2-connector). In any case they ensure an automatic bilateral data import and export.

Answer (score 0):

This would be rather impossible to achieve, as Magento doesn't support many core PIM features, such as **channel management** or **data syndication**. The core features of Magento do not support more than 1 attribute set per product. Instead, a workable combination would be to use Bluestone PIM, coupled with our native Magento Extension. Bluestone PIM would serve as the main product information management platform. Most users have large combined attribute sets, but managing them in a PIM platform, such as Bluestone PIM, is much easier and more efficient.

Our extension also will soon support multiple stores sync for languages, in that the attribute sets for each languages will be all synced. More details here: https://bluestonepim.com/magento-extension